React как передать объект данных между страницами react-router-dom?
У меня в проекте есть 2 страницы, первая создает элементы-вопросы, а вторая их отображает. В первой странице я моделирую вопросы. Вопрос в том, каким образом передавать готовый массив элементов-вопросов между страницами? В виде целого готового array объекта, или используя state managers и обновлять состояние элементов по кусочкам не запихивая все данные в один массив?

Ну скорее всего вам тут ответят "Как вам удобно". Но я лично не совсем понимаю вопроса. Вы пытаетесь спросить, какой state manager использовать для передачи этих данных или про формат данных? Чем вас не устраивает массив с данными?

Покажите пример кода и проблему + желаемое поведение. Не понятно, что такое "обновлять по кусочкам"

@SwaD Я частично понял проблему, я собираю целый огромный объект данных включая subsubchilds и поэтому у меня родительский компонент нагружен кодом обновления состояния этих-же subsubchilds компонентов. Единственная причина по которой я это делаю заключается в том, что мне надо вывести потом эти данные на другой странице. Решают ли State менеджеры эту проблему?

Возможно и то частично. Все зависит от того, что должно отображаться из этого большого объекта на новой странице

@SwaD Вопрос решен, необходимо использовать useReducer hook для более читабельного и организованного кода
